# Internship in New York City

Tags: new, york, city

What companies do you recommend? Where have people had good experiences? Going to start making cold calls. Is this a good idea? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think Nutmeg Post and Gramercy Post take in a lot of interns, so they'd be good places to try. If you want to shoot for the top (and why not?), you should also try C5 and Sound One. Also, off the top of my head, you could try Soundtrack NY.

And, if you're turned down, it's a good idea to politely ask if they can recommend anyone else for you to contact. That way, it's more of a lukewarm call because you can say "XXX at XXX Studio told me i should talk to you".

Best of luck!